# Android POST Request Not Working Properly

Tags: java, android, http, post

I am using the following method for getting time from server with a Post request.

```
    String result = "";
    URL url = null;
    InputStream stream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.118.2/myapi");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("time", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("Submit", "UTF-8");

        urlConnection.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is php script

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["time"]))
    echo "Time";
else
    echo "Invalid Request";
```

But when i call post method, i get resut "Invalid Request".
I almost searched every stackoverflow threads but none of them working, i really wonder what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try.

1) Add the following to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

2) change your PHP file

```
<?php  
    $time   = urldecode($_POST['time']);        
    if($time === NULL) {
        echo "invalid";       
    } else {
        echo "time";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I already added the permision, i also wrote urldecode line but didnt worked :/ $_POST[“time”] is always null.

Comment: whats the filename for your php file? myapi? or myapi.php?

Comment: index.php inside of myapi folder.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with following changes;

```
data = "time=Submit";
...
...
...
url = new URL("http://192.168.118.2/myapi/index.php");
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( data.getBytes().length ));
urlConnection.setUseCaches( false );
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
...
...
...
```